# QComboBox setCurrentIndex by text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a ComboBox with different values inside: Yes, No.

Can I set the ComboBox by a value I receive from an input? I don't want to set it by index#. I also want to try to stay away from if statements.

[image]

I've tried something like this:

```
    self.UnlHE_Drop = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    self.UnlHE_Drop.setObjectName("UnlHE_Drop")
    self.UnlHE_Drop.addItem("")
    self.UnlHE_Drop.setItemText(0, "")
    self.UnlHE_Drop.addItem("")
    self.UnlHE_Drop.addItem("")

def retranslateUi(self, VlS):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    VlS.setWindowTitle(_translate("VlS", "Value"))
    self.UnlHE_Drop.setItemText(1, _translate("VlS", "Yes"))
    self.UnlHE_Drop.setItemText(2, _translate("VlS", "No"))
    self.UnlHE_DropInfo = QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Answer:', 'Yes or No:')
    self.UnlHE_Drop.setCurrentIndex(self.UnlHE_Drop.findText(self.UnlHE_DropInfo))
```

Comment: Which returns the `self.UnlHE_Drop.findText` function?

Comment: what is `UnlHE_Drop`?

Comment: In general the solution seems correct, unless the user places inappropriate values.

Comment: UnlHE_Drop is the name of the combobox. When I try using what i've pasted, it doesn't set value to anything. It's blank and the dropdown is disabled

Comment: Have you added item to QComboBox?

Comment: `self.UnlHE_Drop = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    self.UnlHE_Drop.addItems(["Yes", "No"])`

Comment: Please see updated code, I added values to QComboBox from QtDesigner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to add items to the QComboBox since when you use findText you are looking for those items, Another thing is that QInputDialog.getText returns a tuple, the first is the value entered and the second is a bool that indicates whether you pressed yes or no.

```
self.UnlHE_Drop = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
self.UnlHE_Drop.addItems(["Yes", "No"])
UnlHE_DropInfo, ok = QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Answer:', 'Yes or No:')
if ok:
    self.UnlHE_Drop.setCurrentText(UnlHE_DropInfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the value is already an option int the `QComboBox` you can use `setCurrentText(QString text)` to set it to that value.